# What is this method doing? (Arrays and random numbers)

Tags: java, arrays, random

My textbook gave me this code to help count the amount of times a certain number shows up in an array of integers. I tried to apply the code my textbook gave me to my assignment but it doesn't seem to be working. Basically, I have to generate 30 random integers in an array, with the upper bound being 15 and lower bond being -5.

I want to find out how many times a number in the array is equal to 0, 1, 2... all the way until 10. The first code is the one my textbook gave me. They also used a random number generator but instead of finding how many elements is equal to 0, 1, etc, they want to find how many times each number appears. (The scores array is simply the random number generator, and their upper bound is 100). The second code is mine.

```
int[] counts = new int [100];
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) { 
int index = scores[i]; 
counts[index]++;
}


 //This is my code
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int []a = arrayHist ();
    printArray (a);
}

public static int randomInt (int low, int high) {
    int range = (high - low) +1;
    return (int) (Math.random() * range) + low;

}

public static int[] randomIntArray (int x) {
    int[] random = new int[x];
    for (int i = 0; i< x; i++) {
        random [i] = randomInt (-5, 15);

    }
    return random;
}

public static int[] arrayHist () {
    int[] counts = new int [30];
    int[] hist = randomIntArray (30);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && i >= 0; i++) {
        int index = hist[i];
        counts[index]++;
    }
    return hist;
}


public static void printArray (int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.println (a[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm supposed to be getting only 11 elements, but instead I get 30 random numbers again. Why is that?

Comment: So your array contains thirty random numbers between -5 and 15, but you only want to count the number of times the value is between 0 and 10 ? -5 to -1, and 11 to 15 are not counted?

Comment: Take a close look at `for (int i = 0; i < 10 && i >= 0; i++)` and what you think it is doing vs what it is actually doing. Also, look at what you are returning.

Comment: @CaiusJard yeah that is correct

Comment: I've posted something that will help, without giving you exactly the right answer to paste in - if you're interested in knowing what's going on and working through it. If you want to, perhaps avoid looking at Reiner Wei's answer (unless you're just after an answer to paste) until you've reached the end of your "patience to work this out myself" :) - he's written the answer directly, so you can choose your approach now. Feel free to ask any followup questions in the comments of either answer

Answer (score 1):

I'll put some comments in your code, and see if you can spot where it goes wrong:

```
//take a histogram of the array. We're only going to count values between 0 and 10
//so 25th to 75 centiles, ignoring values that are lower than 0 or higher than 10
public static int[] arrayHist () {

  //need to make an array of 11 numbers for the counts
  int[] counts = new int [30];

  //get an array of 30 random numbers
  int[] hist = randomIntArray (30);

  //loop over the whole array of 30 numbers
  for (int i = 0; i < 10 && i >= 0; i++) {
    //retrieve the random number into a variable temporarily
    int index = hist[i];

    //if the value is too low or too high, skip it

    //else, store it in the counts array - the value from the random array
    //serves as the index position in the counts array        
    counts[index]++;
  }

  //return the counts array
  return hist;
}
```

What I've done with my comments is equivalent to designing the algorithm using the language you think in (English) and then you can translate it into the language you're learning (java). Very few developers think in the programming language they write. As a student I recommend you should ALWAYS write comments to explain your algorithm to yourself before you write code underneath the comments. You get points for writing comments (usually) so if you write them first then a) it helps you write the code and b) you don't have the tedious job of writing comments after you get the code working

Please please, for your own good/learning, try working out what is wrong from the above before looking at the spoilers(answers) below. Roll the mouse over the box to display the spoilers

> ```
>  //loop over the whole array of 30 numbers - YOU ONLY LOOP 10
>  for (int i = 0; i < 10 && i >= 0; i++) {
>    //if the value is too low or too high, skip it - YOU DIDN'T DO THIS CHECK
>    ...
>  }
>  //return the counts array - YOU RETURNED THE WRONG ARRAY
>  return hist;
> ```

**Edits in response to comments:**

*Checking a range*

You'll have to check two limits, and hence it will need to be of one of the following forms:

```
if(x < 0 || x > 10) then don't do the count

if(!(x >= 0 && x <= 10)) then don't do the count

if(x >= 0 && x <= 10) then do the count

if(!(x < 0 || x > 10)) then do the count
```

Tests that use NOT - the exclamation mark `!` - are typically a bit harder to read and understand, so try to avoid them is possible. Tests that are "positive minded" - i.e. they return a positive result rather than a negative that needs to be negated - are easier to read and understand.

A helpful tip for loops and methods, in terms of error checking, is to test for bad values that meet certain conditions, and if a bad value is encountered, then skip processing the rest of the loop (using the `continue`) keyword, or skip the rest of the method (by `return`ing from it)

Doing this means that your if body (the bit between { and  } ) doesnt get massive. Compare:

```
for(...){
  if(test for bad values)
    continue;

  //50 lines long loop body
}
```

Is neater than doing:

```
for(...){
  if(test for goodvalues){
    //50 lines long loop body
  }
}
```

If you use the bottom pattern, you can end up after several IFs in a real indented mess, with { and } all over the place and your code is way over to the right hand side of the screen:

```
    for(...){
        //code
        if(...){
            //code
            if(...){
                //code
                if(...){
                    //code
                    if(...){
                        //code
                        if(...){
                            //code
                            if(...){
                                //code
                            }
                            //code
                        }
                        //code
                    }
                    //code
                }
                //code
            }
            //code
        }
        //code
    }
```

Keeping indent levels to a minimum helps make your code more readable

Hence, I recommend in your case, that rather than test for the value being inside the range 0 to 10 and doing something with it, you adopt the form "if value is OUTSIDE" the range 0 to 10, skip doing the rest of the loop

Comment: To make sure that the number is in between 0 and 10, should I write an if-else statement?

Comment: You should indeed, I'll edit the body of the answer to provide an extended explanation

Comment: @CaiusJard: it's great that you're encouraging the OP to learn for him/herself - so many people just want to grab and run. Remind me in 2 days for a +50 reward for this!

Comment: I should have handed the job of time keeping to my better organised better half :)

Answer (score 0):

Your arrayHist() method just returns the array with the random numbers. It should be more like this:

```
public static int[] arrayHist() {
    // generate array with random numbers
    int[] hist = randomIntArray(30);
    // initialize the array for counting
    int[] counts = new int[11];
    // step through the random numbers array and increase corresponding counter if the number's values is between 0 and 10
    for (int j = 0; j < hist.length; j++) {
        int number = hist[j];
        if (number > -1 && number < 11) {
            counts[number]++;
        }
    }
    return counts;
}
```

Comment: `new int[10]` is more readable than  `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`.

Comment: That's nice, but from the title of the question, and the fact that this is obviously college work, I'd say the "explanation" part is more important than the "right answer" part..